# Word count is wrong when adding new line in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, counter, contenteditable

I count the words in a `contenteditable`. I split it using spaces. The problem comes when you enter a new line. It doesn’t count the word you’re currently writing on the new line until you add a space.

On top of that, in the following example if you split the example text into two lines, it will “eat up” one word when you do that:

http://jsfiddle.net/MrbUK/

I’m guessing this issue exists because between HTML elements there are no spaces:

`<div>some things</div><div>are cool</div>` its string would be *“some thingsare cool”*.

Here’s the code that I have:

```
function wordCount() {
var content_text = $('#post_content').text(),
    char_count = content_text.length,
    word_count = 0;
    // if no characters, words = 0
    if (char_count != 0) 
      word_count = content_text.replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/).length;
$('.word_count').html(word_count + " words &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; " + char_count + " characters");
}
```

I tried replacing some HTML tags:

```
word_count = content_text.replace(/&nbsp;/g, " ").replace(/<div>/g, "<p>").replace(/<\/div>/g, "</p>").replace(/<\/p><p>/g, " ").split(/\s+/).length;
```

without any luck. I need to discard whether it’s a `<p>` or `<div>` and some browsers add `&nbsp;` when merging lines together.

Any ideas? Thanks!

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Jefferson below for his clever method, I managed to solve this. For some reason I have to do -1 on the `word_count` to display the correct number of words:

```
function wordCount() {
  var content_div = $('#post_content'),
      content_text,
      char_count = content_div.text().length,
      word_count = 0;
  // if no characters, words = 0
  if (char_count != 0) 
    content_div.children().each(function(index, el) {
      content_text += $(el).text()+"\n";
    });
  // if there is content, splits the text at spaces (else displays 0 words)
  if (typeof content_text !== "undefined")
    word_count = content_text.split(/\s+/).length - 1;
  $('.word_count').html(word_count + " words &nbsp;&bull;&nbsp; " + char_count + " characters");
}
```

Comment: sashok - excellent question. great detail. thank you for using jsfiddle

Comment: Count is off without even hitting enter: 
`console.log(content_text.replace(/[^\w ]/g, "").split(/\s+/));` First index is a empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$("#post_content").children().each(function(index, el){buffer += $(el).text()+"\n"})
```

This way you iterate by all elements inside your `div` and get only the text, put a "\n" between them.

Comment: `buffer` is a String, I don't put it in the code, but I think you understand how will work this

Comment: Thanks, smart solution. I edited my question with my answer, using your method.

Answer (score 2):

Jefferson's answer was great, and it helped me with this exact same issue.
The problem I encountered was the contents of my `contenteditable` div was not entirely wrapped in HTML tags.

For example, my `div` contained the following HTML code:

```
This is my first line<div>This is my second line</div>
```

By using `$.children()`, it was ignoring the first line and only returning a word count of 5. To get round this I used `$.contents()` instead. Modified code is below:

```
$("#post_content").contents().each(function(index, el){buffer += $(el).text()+"\n"})
```

This returned a line count of 10.

Apologies for adding this as an answer and not as a comment to Jefferson's answer, however my reputation is too low to allow me to do that. I felt it was worth pointing the above out though.